# use a variable index without using a loop

Tags: c#, winforms

i was wondering if there is a way to use an index variable, without using the for or foreach loop, like in this example (what i've made but doesn't work):
i have 3 integer arrays, one goes for the listbox, and when i select an item on the listbox, it would take the index of the selected item, and look for that index inside the other arrays, and put the values of the 2nd and 3rd arrays inside textboxs, here is my code:

```
if (ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = jnames[ListBox1.SelectedIndex];
            TextBox2.Text = enames[ListBox1.SelectedIndex];
        }
```

no errors or exceptions are given, just does nothing.

Comment: That code is perfectly fine.  And it will do nothing when `ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count` is zero.  So what's your question?

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if setting `ListBox1.Text` is messing up `ListBox1.SelectedItem` before you get to the next line.  Single step through using a debugger.

Comment: It should do "something". Have you tried stepping through it with the debugger?

Comment: actually that was a typo and still not working, and even if it was that, textbox2 should have something no ?

Comment: UPDATE: it seems that it only works for the last item, it can only access the 2 arrays in the last item only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SelectedItems` is more suited for a multi-select `ListBox`. You should just use`SelectedIndex` directly:

```
if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = jnames[ListBox1.SelectedIndex];
        TextBox2.Text = enames[ListBox1.SelectedIndex];
    }
```

You should learn to use the debugger. A breakpoint set on the `if` statement will show you if the condition is being met, and whether the code inside the `if` will ever execute.

Comment: your solution is actually not doing a thing, same result, i still can't get strings from jnames and enames :/ textboxes are still empty

Comment: i used the debuger, and yes sir, the code inside If is not executed, but why is that ?
EDIT: it is executed, but nothing happens :s

Comment: Well, you tell me. What did the debugger show the value of `ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count` was?

Comment: it was 1, since i was selecting only one item.

Comment: You're not making sense. If the `ListBox1.SelectedIndex` is 1, the code inside the `if` in  my code **does** execute. (I have a quick test app I just wrote that shows it; it uses two more listboxes instead of two arrays just because it was quicker to write, but it works perfectly.)

Comment: thanks for taking the time, i switched to listview instead of listbox, better and more columns, thanks, ill put your answer as "the" answer :)